# Making the same amount from different combinations of coins (top-down approach)

Tags: python, recursion, interview-questions, combinatorics

I was reading a typical interview question [found here](https://www.interviewcake.com/question/python/coin). Given an `amount` and a list of `denominations`, count the number of possible ways to break the `amount` into different combinations of coins. For example, if `amount = 4` and `denominations=[1, 2, 3]`, there are 4 possibilities. Here's my Python solution.

```
def _get_num_of_changes(amount, denominations, i=0):
    if amount == 0:
        return 1
    elif amount < 0:
        return None
    else:
        s = 0
        for i in range(i, len(denominations)):
            coin = denominations[i]
            if amount - coin < coin:
                c = _get_num_of_changes(amount - coin, denominations, i+1)
            else:
                c = _get_num_of_changes(amount - coin, denominations, i)

            if c:
                s += c
        return s

def get_num_of_changes(amount, denominations):
    return _get_num_of_changes(amount, denominations)

print(get_num_of_changes(4, [1, 2, 3]))
```

This is a top-down solution in the sense that I subtract from the starting `amount` and not try to add coins starting at zero to get to `amount` (which would be a bottom-up solution). Given this difference, I am really interested to see if my solution is good enough, too.

Answer (score 2):

#### Simpler base case

I suggest returning `0` as the base case to avoid the `if c` check di as `x += 0` does not change it.

#### Iterate at a higher level

Use `for item in collection` not `range(len`. The index can be obtained with `enumerate`.

#### Avoid repetition

You repeat `_get_num_of_changes(amount - coin, denominations,` twice, use a ternary conditional expression to avoid it.

#### Avoid manual summing

Starting at \$0\$ and writing `+=` is too manual in Python, I suggest using `sum`.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean in your third point. Wouldn't using a ternary expression in this case make a really long line (which one would generally like to avoid)?

Comment: @bourbaki4481472 Just use a temporary variabile.

Answer (score 2):

The function is computing rather than retrieving, so I wouldn't have "get" in the function name.

If the `amount` is negative, then there are zero ways to make the amount.  There's no need to treat `None` as a special case.

Repurposing `i` in `for i in range(i, len(denominations))` is confusing.  The code would be clearer if you renamed the loop variable to `j` or something.

Still, having `i` as a parameter at all is awkward.  I'd rather change the recursion strategy altogether.  Instead of trying to use one of each denomination, why not exhaust one denomination altogether?

```
def num_change_combinations(amount, denominations):
    if amount == 0:
        return 1
    elif amount < 0 or not denominations:
        return 0
    else:
        coin = denominations[-1]
        return sum(
            num_change_combinations(amt, denominations[:-1])
            for amt in range(amount, -1, -coin) 
        )
```

Comment: Great comment on the use of the word "get." This actually will help me write functions in the future because I am always confused when to use get vs compute (or make).